# Flutter: when I click on other widget, SelectableText not deselect

Tags: flutter, flutter-desktop

when selecting text from SelectableText and wanting to change the selected text both SelectableText remain as they're selected.

[image]

Code:

```
Column(
children:[
 SelectableText(
      '1004',
      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText2,
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
    ),
SelectableText(
      '1005',
      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText2,
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
    ),
]
)
```

*I used 2 separated SelectableText.

Comment: Try giving each one of them a unique key and share what happens next please

Comment: @BaselAbuhadrous I did it and still not working.

Comment: Which version on Flutter are you on?

Comment: @Dani3le_ Flutter (Channel stable, 2.10.0, on macOS 11.6 20G165 darwin-x64, locale en-IQ)

Comment: also had this is issue , using flutter 2.10

Comment: Same issue with flutter 3.0.5

Answer (score 0):

You can use this widget.

`SelectionArea(child: Text("Selectable text"))`